# Load local file and get Unknown chromium error: -6

Tags: android, url, webview, local, chromium

I was trying to load a local file from the sdcard into a WebView. But since Android 4.1 it isn't working anymore, I always get the message: File not found and in LogCat

```
Unknown chromium error: -6.
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I figured out the Problem and I just needed to add one more slash.
Example:

We need now:

```
loadURL("file:///.../file.file");
```

instead of:

```
loadURL("file://.../file.file");
```

Just add one more slash and it works. I hope this is helpful for all with the same issue under Android 4.1.